# Where is type [Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy]?

Tags: oracle, powershell, ado, bulk

I tried

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Oracle.DataAccess") 
$bulkCopy = new-object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy $oraClientConnString
```

and got

```
GAC    Version        Location                                                                                                                                                 
---    -------        --------                                                                                                                                                 
True   v2.0.50727     C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Oracle.DataAccess\2.111.6.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll                                                           
New-Object : Cannot find type [Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:3 char:23
+ $bulkCopy = new-object <<<<  Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy $oraClientConnString
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Cf. [OracleBulkCopy Class](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14435_01/win.111/e10927/OracleBulkCopyClass.htm)

What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're using an older version of Oracle? I see documentation for this class on Oracle for 11g or later.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E10927_01/OracleBulkCopyClass.htm

Oracle.DataClient.dll is the containing assembly in the above documentation.

Try this:

```
ps> $a = [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("oracle.dataaccess")
ps> $a.getexportedtypes() | where { $_.fullname -like "*bulk*" }
```

-Oisin

Comment: Yes I needed a new version. Now I have version still v2.0.50727 but Location C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\oracle.dataaccess\2.112.2.0__89b483f429c47342\oracle.dataaccess.dll . Works great and fast. I tried especially CLOB columns. I seems to be the best way to copy table content to an Oracle database.

Comment: Full PowerShell script to copy a table to Oracle at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343299/bulk-insert-to-oracle-using-net/4918808#4918808