# DataTable To database Update oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need help regarding following issue.
I am dealing with grid view in asp.net. In this grid view data is bound from a datatable. all insertion, updation and deletion is performed in datatable. On save button click i want this datatable to be updated in database table(database table already exist with some data which is edited in datatable, Datatabase tables columns are same as datatable).

I tried following with oracleBulkCopy

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy oracleBulkCpoy = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy(DM.ConnectionString);
oracleBulkCpoy.DestinationTableName = "RANGE";
oracleBulkCpoy.WriteToServer(dtRange);
```

Above code only writing all rows in database table. it is not updating existing rows but creating same row aging with same primary key id.

Do I need any stored procedure?

Any other Suggestions or idea of updating datatable into database...

Plz help.. suggestions, opinions are welcome...
Thanx in advance

Comment: Posting some code would help @pramod

Comment: this may be helpful http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/OracleBulkCopyClass.htm and also have a look at this pld SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343299/bulk-insert-to-oracle-using-net

Comment: Thanx for ur response its working.. but when i am writing oracleBulkCopy.WriteToServer it is not editing in existing rows in database table but it is creating same rows again...

Comment: can you update your code @pramod with the changes

Comment: Edited in my question @Devjosh

Comment: i never used oracle sqlbulkcopy so see this link if there is something useful in it http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7287/what-specifically-does-oraclebulkcopy-do-and-how-can-i-optimize-its-performance or http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15296_01/doc.111/e15167.pdf